# Getting Same Image from Three upload controls in one view MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have three file upload control, All accepts single file but when i am getting in view all are saving as same image in my image folder  -

my model is below in model i took HttpPostedFileBase type three variables and three label variable:

```
 [NotMapped]
    [DisplayName("Upload Image")]
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public HttpPostedFileBase ImageFile { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [DisplayName("Upload Aadhaar Card")]
    public string AadhaarPathL { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public HttpPostedFileBase AadhaarFile{get;set;}
    [NotMapped]
    [DisplayName("Upload PAN Card")]
    public string   PanPathL           { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public HttpPostedFileBase PanFile { get; set; }
```

In View i declared file type text bos for uploading the image  :

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateVendor", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<div style="margin-left:70px;">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImagePath)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ImageFile, new { type = "file", name = "ImageFile", id = "ImageFile",@class= "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ImagePath, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AadhaarPathL)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AadhaarFile,new { type = "file", name = "AadhaarFile", id = "AadhaarFile", @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AadhaarPathL, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PanPathL)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PanFile, new { type = "file", name = "PanFile", id = "PanFile", @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PanPathL, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                @* Empty  *@
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
}
```

And finally in View code i am getting one by one both uri and image but everytime i am getting saved same image for every image . i am stucked here

```
    [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateVendor(VendorList vendorList)
        {
 #region Photo Image 
                string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(vendorList.ImageFile.FileName);
                string extension = Path.GetExtension(vendorList.ImageFile.FileName);
                fileName = fileName + "Photo" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + extension;

                var uri = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}{3}",
                 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme,
                 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host,
                 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Port == 80 ? string.Empty : ":" + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Port,
                 "/Image/" + fileName);

                vendorList.ImagePath = "~/Image/" + fileName;

                fileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Image/"), fileName);
                vendorList.ImageFile.SaveAs(fileName);
                vendorList.PhotoPath = fileName;

                vendorList.PhotoUrl = uri;
                #endregion
                #region Aadhaar Image 
                string fileAadhaarName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(vendorList.AadhaarFile.FileName);
                string extensionAadhaar = Path.GetExtension(vendorList.AadhaarFile.FileName);
                fileAadhaarName = fileAadhaarName + vendorList.Email + "Aadhaar" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + extensionAadhaar;

                var uriAadhaar = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}{3}",
                 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme,
                 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host,
                 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Port == 80 ? string.Empty : ":" + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Port,
                 "/Image/" + fileAadhaarName);

                vendorList.AadhaarPathL = "~/Image/" + fileAadhaarName;

                fileAadhaarName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Image/"), fileAadhaarName);
                vendorList.ImageFile.SaveAs(fileAadhaarName);
                vendorList.AadhaarPath = fileAadhaarName;

                vendorList.AadhaarUrl = uriAadhaar;
                #endregion
                #region Pan Image 
                string filePanName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(vendorList.PanFile.FileName);
                string extensionPan = Path.GetExtension(vendorList.PanFile.FileName);
                filePanName = filePanName + vendorList.Email + "Pan" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + extensionPan;

                var uriPan = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}{3}",
                 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme,
                 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host,
                 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Port == 80 ? string.Empty : ":" + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Port,
                 "/Image/" + filePanName);

                vendorList.PanPathL = "~/Image/" + filePanName;

                filePanName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Image/"), filePanName);
                vendorList.ImageFile.SaveAs(filePanName);
                vendorList.PanPath = filePanName;

                vendorList.PanUrl = uriPan;

}
```

Can someone suggest what is happening here .

Comment: Just a suggestion: Instead of declaring 3 `HttpPostedFileBase` properties separately, you can use single `List<HttpPostedFileBase>` property and use `multiple` setting on file input, then you can limit uploaded files to maximum of 3 files.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, thanks for suggestion , but my problem is how i will identify that which image is for which field